# How to display a Flag in a tpl file for different View modes?

Tags: 7, flags, entities

There is no field in manage display of content type to display Flag link.
There is a tpl file (**node--article--teaser.tpl.php**) for teaser mode displaying bookmark

```
<?php if (isset($content['links']['flag'])) : ?>
    <?php echo render($content['links']['flag']);?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But for another mode this having View mode *teaser_2_col* and tpl file name **node--teaser-2-col.tpl.php**, `$content['links']` does not have a Flag element.

Answer (score 2):

You actually *can* display a Flag link as a pseudofield, which can be ordered among other entity elements in the *Manage display* settings for an entity type. Go to `admin/structure/flags` and pick the Flag that you need. Next, check *Display link as field* in the section *Display in entity links*. You can now use the link in your template files by rendering the node and getting the right field (use [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) for this).

Alternatively, you can output a Flag link by using [`flag_create_link($flag_name, $entity_id)`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!flag!flag.module/function/flag_create_link/7). In that case you don't need a pseudofield.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flag_create_link()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!flag!flag.module/function/flag_create_link/7) function to create the link and print it.

*Usage:*

If the flag was created for the content type, then the flag can be printed using:

```
<?php print flag_create_link('flag_machine_name', $node->nid); ?>
```

**Note:** The second argument is *the id of the entity for which the flag was created*.